Using AMPL C++ API in QT
I'm new in Qt c++ designer. I want to use the AMPL API in C++ with Qt for solving my optimization problem. How do I integrate it into my project and .pro file? Here's the code in my .pro file:
QT = core

CONFIG += c++17 cmdline

#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

INCLUDEPATH += /home/*/*/ampl.linux-intel64/amplapi/include

and i have this simple code in my main.cpp:
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "ampl/ampl.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    // Create an AMPL instance
    // ampl::AMPL ampl;
    ampl::Environment env("/home/*/*/ampl.linux-intel64/");
    ampl::AMPL ampl(env);
    // std::cout << ampl.getOption("version").value() << std::endl;
    return a.exec();
}

But there are many errors showing and It couldn't find the class for ampl. How can I solve this problem? I have attached a screenshot of them below. 
how to correct the linker or library?
help me.

RTFM https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries
